# How to make fragment A know that button in fragment B is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

a bit complex but I'll try to explain.
I have 3 fragments.
First Fragment (NoteFragment) holds the recycler view of all notes.
Second Fragment (AddNoteFragment) opens when I click the Add Note button, which is this button in the first Fragment.
A third fragment (RemoveNoteFragment) is a fragment that appears after I click on one of the notes. (I have a listener in the NoteAdapter).

First fragment and second fragment appear in the same frame layout.
In a second fragment I have a button that as soon as I click it I want to delete the note (from recycler view and firebase - see the code how i do it).

Note Fragment

```
public class NoteFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView RVNotesList;
    private ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    private NotesAdapter adapter;
    private ImageView mAddNoteBTN;
    private Note note;
    private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase db;
    private DatabaseReference users;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private Fragment removeFragment;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_notes, container, false);
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        removeFragment = new RemoveNoteFragment();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Notes");
        mAddNoteBTN = view.findViewById(R.id.addNoteBTN);
        mAddNoteBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
        RVNotesList = view.findViewById(R.id.RVNotesList);
        users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                notes.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    note = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Note.class);
                    notes.add(note);
                    keys.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                }
                adapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, getActivity(), keys);
                if (adapter.getItemCount() <= 3) {
                    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
                } else {
                    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
                }
                RVNotesList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                RVNotesList.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setOnNoteClickListener(new NotesAdapter.OnNoteClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNoteClick(final int position) {
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottom_container, removeFragment)
                                .commit();
                        String key = keys.get(position);
                        users.child(key).removeValue();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.addNoteBTN:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_left_to_right, R.anim.exit_left_to_right).replace(R.id.bottom_container, new AddNoteFragment())
                        .commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Add Note Fragment

```
public class AddNoteFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AddNotePresenter {

    private EditText ETnoteTitle, ETnoteDesc;
    private TextView TVnoteLastDate;
    private Button saveNoteBTN, deleteNoteBTN, BTNtaskDatePicker;
    private Note note;

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    private Calendar c;
    private DatePickerDialog dpd;

    private AddNoteView addNoteView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note, container, false);

        addNoteView = new AddNoteView(this);
        ETnoteTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.noteTitle);
        ETnoteDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.noteDesc);
        TVnoteLastDate = view.findViewById(R.id.TVnoteLastDate);
        BTNtaskDatePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.taskDatePicker);
        BTNtaskDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        saveNoteBTN = view.findViewById(R.id.saveNoteBTN);
        saveNoteBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
        deleteNoteBTN = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteNoteBTN);
        deleteNoteBTN.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.saveNoteBTN:
                saveNote();
                hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                break;
            case R.id.deleteNoteBTN:
                removeAddNoteFragment();
                hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                break;
            case R.id.taskDatePicker:
                showDatePicker();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAddNoteFragment() {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_container)).commit();
    }

    public void showDatePicker() {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay) {
                day = mDay;
                month = mMonth + 1;
                year = mYear;
                TVnoteLastDate.setText(mDay + "/" + (mMonth + 1) + "/" + mYear);
            }
        }, day, month, year);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        dpd.show();
    }

    public void saveNote() {
        String title = ETnoteTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String desc = ETnoteDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        String date = TVnoteLastDate.getText().toString().trim();
        if (title.isEmpty() || desc.isEmpty() || date.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        note = new Note(title, desc, day, month, year);
        addNoteView.pushNote(note);
    }

    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Remove Note Fragment

```
public class RemoveNoteFragment extends Fragment{

    private ImageView IVremoveNote;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remove_note, container, false);
        IVremoveNote = view.findViewById(R.id.IVremoveNote);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Note Adapter

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> keys;
    private OnNoteClickListener onNoteClickListener;

    public NotesAdapter(ArrayList<Note> notes, Context context, ArrayList<String> k) {
        this.notes = notes;
        this.context = context;
        this.keys = k;
    }

    public interface OnNoteClickListener {
        void onNoteClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnNoteClickListener(OnNoteClickListener onNoteClickListener) {
        this.onNoteClickListener = onNoteClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_list_item, parent, false);
        return new NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Note note = notes.get(position);
        holder.TVnoteCardTitle.setText(notes.get(position).getmNoteTitle());
        holder.TVnoteCardDesc.setText(notes.get(position).getmNoteDescription());
        String lastDayToConfirmNote = (notes.get(position).getmDay() + "/"
                + notes.get(position).getmMonth() + "/" + notes.get(position).getmYear());
        holder.TVnoteCardLastDate.setText(lastDayToConfirmNote);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    public class NotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView TVnoteCardTitle;
        private TextView TVnoteCardDesc;
        private TextView TVnoteCardLastDate;


        public NotesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TVnoteCardTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVnoteCardTitle);
            TVnoteCardDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVnoteCardDesc);
            TVnoteCardLastDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVnoteCardLastDate);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (onNoteClickListener != null) {
                        onNoteClickListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

what do I want ?
I want that once I click on the IVremoveNote that is inside the RemoveNoteFragment, my NoteFragment knows this, and I can do the actions within it (in NoteFragment) .

Or if you have another solution for deleting a note, I'd love to hear.

Notice that for deleting the note, I use the listener inside the note adapter, which accepts the keys array list position.

Comment: normally you would pass data through interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to make a method in NoteFragment and then call the method when IVremoveNote in RemoveNoteFragment is pressed.
In this method, you can add the functionality to remove the node/row.
Tip! - you can pass the note/row information in the method argument.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Rishabh Sharma, Thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry, but I didn't understand what you meant, could you drop a little detail please?

Comment: Step 1: add a method in NoteFragment. Make sure to add an argument for Note to be customized and then add the functionality in this method (removing the Note in your case).
Step 2: In your OnClickListener method in RemoveNoteFragment pass the information about the note to be removed.
Note: you can set the argument for position.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these fragments are hosted by the same activity. You can call an activity's method from a fragment by `((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();`

There you can write your logic to call the fragments method, listener or whatever

Answer (score 0):

You should really think about using LiveData and ViewModel from the Architecture components for your purpose, which is a recommended design pattern by Google. It needs a bit of time to get the hang of it, but you can use it for almost every app and it will make your problem really easy. See the following [overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for example.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118) is a very good YouTube tutorial that describes exactly your note example, not for Firebase but for Android Room (local db instead of cloud). Its a bit lengthy but you will have a good understanding afterwards.

Basically from your Firebase db you query all notes to receive a LiveData> allNotes

You can then observe the LiveData allNotes to get the list and set it to your RecyclerView. This way, you will always have up-to-date data in your recyclerview.
When you delete a note from the db, it will automatically update the list and show it in recyclerview.